# Why are only the non-empty non-null Java expressions evaluated to wrong values in jsp/Tomcat 8?

Tags: java, maven, jsp, tomcat, el

Why are **ALL** the jsp **Java expressions** evaluated to empty values if **not all** contain null/empty values? The expressions **ARE** evaluated, but not to the correct values.

This was working at some point, then I had to do some other changes and only now I noticed that the expressions are not working anymore. I tried to revert my other changes, to bring the code to a a minimum as shown below, but it's still not working. Any idea what I'm doing wrong/missing below?
I'm running the webapp in Tomcat 8.5.

This is what's in **index.jsp**:

```
<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %> 
<%@ page import="com.aif.User" %>

<html>
    <head>
    </head>

    <%
    User user = new User();
    String emptyString = "";
    String nonEmptyString = "NonEmptyStringValue";
    %>

    <body>
        Java scriptlet with null value: '<%=user.getName()%>' <br /><br />

        Java expression with null value: '${user.getName()}' should display '' <br /><br />

        Java expression with empty value: '${emptyString}' should display '' <br /><br />

        Java expression with non-empty non-null value: '${nonEmptyString}' should display 'NonEmptyStringValue' <br /><br />

    </body>
</html>
```

The above evaluates to this in the browser:

```
Java scriptlet with null value: 'null' 

Java expression with null value: '' should display '' 

Java expression with empty value: '' should display '' 

Java expression with non-empty non-null value: '' should display 'NonEmptyStringValue'
```

What's in **User.java**

```
package com.aif;

public class User {
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

What's in **web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app>
</web-app>
```

What's in **pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                             http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.aif</groupId>
    <artifactId>xyz2</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

</project>
```

Comment: `user.getName` is null because you never set it

Comment: **user.getName** of course should be null. My question is why are **ALL** Java expression ${} evaluated to empty values even if they are not all null/empty values.

Comment: is this line your only problem: 
Java expression with non-empty non-null value: '${nonEmptyString}' should display 'NonEmptyStringValue' <br /><br /> ??

Comment: looking at browser output, everything looks expected except this line, is that the problem you have?

Comment: @vvtx yes, that line is the problem: **'${nonEmptyString}'** should display **'NonEmptyStringValue'** but instead it displays **''**

Comment: for that you need to attach the property 'nonEmptyString' to some jsp context. e.g. pagecontext, then you can access this in el expression. e.g. :
<% pageContext.setAttribute("nonEmptyString", "NonEmptyStringValue"); 
    %>

Comment: @vvtx, can't that be done automcatically somehow?

Comment: No. Sorry. EL need properties in page/request/session/application scope only

Comment: The problem we are having is that we moved from Weblogic to Tomcat and all variables that are set to **null** are now displayed with a value of **null** in the browser. Weblogic was displaying all null variables as empty values in the browser. We're trying to do the same in Tomcat now. That's why I was trying to just replace all scriptlets of this type **<%= =>** with Java expressions **${ }**, but if that's not enough and we'd have to also add all the values manually in the jsp context, that will require too much manual work and we'll have to find a different solution. What else can we try?

Comment: I am not sure about Weblogic but tomcat does not show null if datatype is string, it shows blank string. And yes for EL you have to have contexted property  at least for tomcat.

Comment: In the code above is running in Tomcat 8.5 and when **'<%=user.getName()%>'** receives a **null String** to display, it's displaying it in the browser as **'null'** not **''**. Printing **null** values for null variables seems to be the expected behavior in Tomcat: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095419/how-can-i-get-tomcat-to-output-empty-string-instead-of-null

Comment: <%=%> this is expression tag which will show "null" for null stringtype values, I was talking about null stringtype values inside EL {} , which will always show blank string for null string.

Comment: @vvtx Yes that is happening: variables set to null or empty values are displayed by ${} as empty values. So **the expressions are evaluated**. I don't understand why PM77-1 and BlausC consider that the Java expressions above are **not** evaluated. The problem is that when **${}** receive a non-empty non-null value, they are still displayed as an empty value.

Comment: In the end I used this solution with our existing Java scriptlets because it's the one involving the least amount of code changes: I overwrote JspWriter, JspFactory and PageContext: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29508245/jsp-using-a-delegate-for-out-jspwriter-with-jsp-includes-to-change-the-beh